# All System calls require SSDT on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, operating-system

i try to learn internals of Windows OS.
is SSDT defined as "all system calls address list" ?
is SSDT also interrupt handling mechanism that allows to catch hardware events? 
Thanks for answers now.

Comment: One question per question.  Because you can only mark one answer correct.

Comment: done , just one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SSDT is not how the OS catches hardware events. If we start at the hardware, say a PCI card for a network adapter, it will have a signal of type interrupt, which via the PCI interface goes to an interrupt controller. In a PC, that would be an "APIC" (Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller), which in turn is connected to the processor core(s) themselves. Other hardware works in a similar way, so I will use APIC as the example below.

When the OS initializes the APIC, it will give each hardware interrupt a "vector", which goes into the interrupt vector table - each interrupt vector entry will contain an address to which the processor jumps when that interrupt is active. In x86, the interrupt vector table is called "Interrupt Descriptor Table", because the vector is more than a simple address to jump to - it also contains a little bit of extra information about HOW to deal with the interrupt and so on.

So when our network adapter receives a packet of data, it will "pull" the interrupt signal active. The processor will then detect the interrupt, and when it does, the interrupt controller gives the vector to use. The processor looks up the vector, saves the current state, and jumps to the address in the vector.

Inside the vector, the OS will do some "admin" work, and then look up which device driver has asked to be informed about this interrupt, so the OS finds our network adapter driver, and calls it's interrupt handling routine. The interrupt handling code checks the state of the network adapter, sees that it was a "new packet arrived" type of interrupt, reads out the data from the buffer and probably updates some semaphore or similar so that some driver function can start to execute the "we've recieved a new packet" code. Once that is done the interrupt handler returns back to the OS.

On return from the interrupt handling code, the OS will check if any "new process got wakened up", so the process waiting for packets will now be "runnable", and it may switch process at this point, or just mark it as "run this in the future".

The SSDT is used for when an application calls, say, `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile` and `CloseHandle`, and any other system calls (there are quite a lot of them). Basically, there is an entry in the SSDT for `NtCreateFile`, another for `NtReadFile` and so on - note that `NtCreateFile` is not exactly the same as `CreateFile` - it is the part that happens inside the OS Kernel.

Comment: So , when interrupt is fired , all CPU cores will catch it , even any core which is not waiting for interrupt.

Comment: CPU's are not "waiting for interrupt" (although a CPU may be "halted" if there is nothing to do, in which case it comes out of of the halt when it receives an interrupt). And only one CPU will take an interrupt. Typically the APIC is programmed to give the interrupt to a particular CPU. There are also "Inter Processor Interrupts", that are triggered by one CPU to "call" another CPU, this is used by the scheduler to wake CPU's that are halted, but the CPU may also wake on its own when an interrupt comes in on a piece of hardware "it is responsible for". It's a complex matter...